# SQL Server can not save Autogrowth changes

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

When I have change Enable Autogrowth checkbox (set to true) and save it (Ok) And when I go back to the Change Autogrowth  for ..... I see that the changes have not been saved.

SQL Server 2008R2 (I go through == Right click on db, Select properties, Files tab, click on Autogrowth button)

What should I do to be saved changes?

Comment: Use `ALTER DATABASE` in a query window instead of the buggy GUI.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks but does not work

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? How are you validating that it "does not work"? Because the same buggy UI that is not letting you change the value, doesn't show you the changed value? What does the system catalog say?

Comment: Do you have permissions to nake such changes?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Doesn't show me the new value and I did not check result on when the database size increases.

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov User is sa

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is my solution:

Detach the database then delete log file and attach mdf file.

Right now, Enable Autogrowth works.

Answer (score 2):

This code will tell you what you have, change it, and show the new value. Adjust DB name, logfile name and filegrowth size (KB or MB and *8*1024).

```
USE [YourDB]
Go
SELECT growth*8 as filegrowth_KB FROM sys.database_files Where name = N'YourDB_log'
Go

USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [YourDB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'YourDB_log', FILEGROWTH = 1024KB) -- adjust size here
GO

USE [YourDB]
Go
SELECT growth*8 as filegrowth_KB FROM sys.database_files Where name = N'YourDB_log'
GO
```